# How to ignore loading huge fields in django admin list_display?

Tags: python, django, gis, bigdata

I'm using django 1.9 and `django.contrib.gis` with an `Area` model that has a huge gis `MultiPolygonField`:

```
# models.py
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gis_models

class Area(gis_models.Model):

    area_color = gis_models.IntegerField()
    mpoly = gis_models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Area'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Areas'
```

I have the associated `AreaAdmin` class to manage the `Area`s inside django admin:

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib.gis import admin as gis_admin

class AreaAdmin(gis_admin.OSMGeoAdmin):
    map_width = 800
    map_height = 600
    modifiable = False
    list_display = ['area_color', ]
    exclude = ['mpoly', ]
gis_admin.site.register(Area, AreaAdmin)
```

The problem is that even though I'm using `list_display` that doesn't contain `mpoly` and the `exclude` attribute to prevent it's display in the form view , when displaying the list view, it still fetches all the fields from the database and loads it into memory. Because the `mpoly` is so huge, I'm having random errors (segfault, processed killed, ...) and the list display takes many minutes to display some simple integer fields...

Is there any way to tell django not to load the `mpoly` into memory, to ignore it completely in it's database query so it will load fast ? I haven't found anything in the documentation aside from `exclude` to remotely achieve this. I'm asking here in case I'm missing something.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try to override the `get_queryset` method used in generating the list view for `AreaAdmin`.

```
class AreaAdmin(gis_admin.OSMGeoAdmin):

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(AreaAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        
        # tell Django to not retrieve mpoly field from DB
        qs = qs.defer('mpoly') 
        return qs
```

For more information on `defer` see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#defer