# Large Model Fields causing MemoryError when listed in admin site

Tags: python, django, memory

I have the following model:

```
class TemplateModel(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} - Template - {1} - {2}".format(self.id, str(self.self.field2).upper(), str(self.self.field3))

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.id < other.id

    # primary key
    id = models.FloatField(primary_key=True, blank=True)

    # other small fields
    field2 = models.CharField('abbreviation', max_length=10, default=None, editable=False)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=None, editable=False)
    field4 = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default=None, editable=False)

    # very large field, up to 100MB large
    json_data = models.TextField(editable=False)
```

When I try to view this model in the admin console (I can view the listing for all of the various models in my project, a list of objects that I can then click and edit from there), I sometimes (inconsistently) get MemoryErrors or OperationalErrors. The request also takes a long time to complete. This makes me think that the backend is loading the `json_data` field completely every time, which takes a lot of memory and is in this case completely unnecessary.

This started happening when I had around 18 or 19 instances in the database, and has become more frequent since. I mitigated the problem by adding more RAM to the server (the server is low-RAM, just a regular 2GB virtual machine), but only slightly, and this solution is not scalable.

My other attempted solution was to follow the advice of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774028/how-to-ignore-loading-huge-fields-in-django-admin-list-display) and add the following method to the model:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(TemplateModel, self).get_queryset(request)
    # tell Django to not retrieve json_data field from DB
    qs = qs.defer('json_data')
    return qs
```

but this didn't fix the problem. Ideally I would just stop `json_data` from being pulled from the database, as I don't need it until a later time and at that time there's no problem since I'm only accessing one `TemplateModel` instance at a time. How can I do that?

---

Here's the entire traceback:

```
MemoryError traceback:

File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  607.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1803.             'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  250.         self._fetch_all()
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1183.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  54.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1093.                 return list(result)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in cursor_iter
  1462.         for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in <lambda>
  1462.         for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in inner
  96.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
Exception Type: MemoryError at /admin/my_site/templatemodel/


-----------------
OperationalError traceback:


File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in inner
  96.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
The above exception (Could not decode to UTF-8 column 'json_data' with text '{"key": "OoX9J5r6wM6LRGdjKNxNrTOWwj2j1CgL1BssDgC/GhXhKBGLcfeKgRtvb4LX3uUazHaDDaB6syjhKSP+d0W3XDD4bX/U9G8sg24FAXJl0mwaKhDiA68MYJXPuNqunLf+gmH1v) was the direct cause of the following exception:
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  607.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  45.         return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1803.             'selection_note': _('0 of %(cnt)s selected') % {'cnt': len(cl.result_list)},
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  250.         self._fetch_all()
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1183.             self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  54.         results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1093.                 return list(result)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in cursor_iter
  1462.         for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in <lambda>
  1462.         for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in inner
  96.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "/opt/my_site/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in inner
  96.                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/my_site/templatemodel/
Exception Value: Could not decode to UTF-8 column 'json_data' with text '{"key": "OoX9J5r6wM6LRGdjKNxNrTOWwj2j1CgL1BssDgC/GhXhKBGLcfeKgRtvb4LX3uUazHaDDaB6syjhKSP+d0W3XDD4bX/U9G8sg24FAXJl0mwaKhDiA68MYJXPuNqunLf+gmH1v
```

This short segment of the JSON is at the beginning of the huge JSON area, though this isn't even the entire value for this key, much less the second key or further.

Comment: I realized my answer below does not solve your problem. But looking at the link you provided: It adds the get_queryset to the ModelAdmin. You said you added the method to your model. Could that be the issue?

Comment: @Chris yep, that'd do it. Silly of me to overlook that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it help creating a custom ModelAdmin to define the fields you need, leaving out the json_data field?

```
class TemplateModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    exclude = ('json_data',)

admin.site.register(TemplateModel, TemplateModelAdmin)
```

Also, put your `get_queryset()` method in this class instead of in the Model itself, as it was in the link you provided.

Comment: Nope. Tried this, no effect. I think this would only effect the object's actual entry in the admin console, which isn't the issue - rather, it's the list of *all* `TemplateModel`s that I get through the Admin console, from which I can select one.